# page loading twice while rewrite module

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have follwing code in .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule tricks tricks.php?show=all [NC,L]
RewriteRule tricks/ tricks.php?show=all [NC,L]
```

I don't know why my page is loading twice

Comment: What do you mean "loading twice"? You mean it refreshes when it tries to load, or you see the same output twice?

Comment: It seems likely that the problem lies in your PHP then - can you post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file  in the root directory of your site.

It will prevent the looping present in your example

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if not an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#if not already tricks.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !tricks\.php$ [NC]
#rewrite to tricks.php 
RewriteRule ^tricks/?$ tricks.php?show=all [NC,L]
```

> ok it's working now Please give me more Rewrite rule for this tricks/13 will treat as tricks.php?show=one&tid=12 and tricks/ec will trat as tricks.php?show=frmsec&sec=ec

You can replace the above with the solution below which includes the additional requirements you had.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if an existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#do nothing
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^tricks/ec$ tricks.php?show=frmsec&sec=ec [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tricks/13$ tricks.php?show=one&tid=12 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^tricks/?$ tricks.php?show=all [NC,L]
```

Comment: @BhavikPatel edited to prevent existing files (and directories too) from being affected to fix css/resource issues

Comment: ok it's working now 
Please give me more Rewrite rule for this 
tricks/13
will treat as 
tricks.php?show=one&tid=12
and 
tricks/ec
will trat as 
tricks.php?show=frmsec&sec=ec

Comment: sec parameter will be any  string while tid is any number ............ec is not fixed for sec parameter

Answer (score 0):

Check all images "src=" in your HTML. If one of your images doesn't exists, browser will reload the page twice.